# How do I sort this list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in the middle of making a leaderboard, currently I am taking data from a txt file and dumping it into a list.

The list's format looks something like this:

`[['56', 'UsernameA'], ['73', 'UsernameB'], ['52', 'UsernameC'], ['10', 'UsernameD']]`

I would like to create a leaderboard, therefore I would like to sort the list from the highest number to the lowest, I've tried using the `sort()` function, however this only works on integers and my list contains the username and the score, so I cannot convert it into an integer, unless I'm completely wrong here.

Comment: `sorted(your_list, reverse=True)` ...

Comment: just make sure you use `int(x[0])` in the key argument while sorting, to avoid alphabetic sorting of the number strings.

Comment: Or better `your_list.sort(reverse=True)` to save memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you can use the `sorted()` function or `.sort()` method.

I can see two options to sort in the way you want; both required basing the sort on the first element of the sub-lists; which must be converted to integers.

You can then either base it directly on this heuristic, but then you will have to use `reverse=True` as an argument to the function so that you get highest to lowest sorting. Or, you can just use a little hack and sort based on the negative of each of these integers :).

```
l = [['56', 'UsernameA'], ['73', 'UsernameB'], ['52', 'UsernameC'], ['10', 'UsernameD']]
l.sort(key=lambda j: -int(j[0]))
```

which modifies `l` to:

```
[['73', 'UsernameB'], ['56', 'UsernameA'], ['52', 'UsernameC'], ['10', 'UsernameD']]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you! Also nice trick. People really be flagging my question as a duplicate although I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: @PyTest No problem! Enjoy it :)